# Prove that $U_1\cup U_2$ is a subspace of $V$ $\iff$ $U_1\subseteq U_2$ or $U_2\subseteq U_1$ $\triangle$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-verification

Let $V$ be a vector space over some field. Let $U_1$ be a subspace of $V$. Let $U_2$ be a subspace of $V$. Prove that $U_1\cup U_2$ is a subspace of $V$ is equivalent to $U_1\subseteq U_2$ or $U_2\subseteq U_1$

> Conditions for being a subspace
>
> - zero vector in
> - closure under addition in
> - closure under scalar multiplication in

The first condition is trivial.

The second condition:  Let $u,v\in U_1\cup U_2$ then $u,v\in U_1$ or $u,v\in U_2$ or ($u\in U_1$ and $v\in U_2$) without lack of rigor

Case (1) $u,v\in U_1\iff u+v\in U_1$ hence $u+v\in U_1$ (we have $U_2\subseteq U_1$)

Case (2) $u,v\in U_2\iff u+v\in U_2$ hence $u+v\in U_2$ (we have $U_1\subseteq U_2$)

Case (3) $u\in U_1, v\in U_2$ then $u+v\in U_1\cup U_2$ if and only if $u=v$ (how can i prove that???) we have the case $(U_1\subseteq U_2)$

The other condition is also trivial (or not?)

How can I improve my proof? Is it right?

Comment: I did a search on this site for "union subspace" and found at least six posts where this has been discussed already.

Comment: If one of the subspaces is contained in the other, then their union is just the bigger subspace, which is by definition a subspace. Now, if neither is contained in the other, then each of then has one vector that the other one does not. Add two such vectors, and see that the result is outside the union. Then you're done.

Comment: @Arthur So i'm complicating this stuff? had to think in simpler forms

Comment: @MJD I'm asking about whether my proof is right, this is different no?. sorry i'm new here i don't know the rules

Comment: @Arthur If $U_2\subseteq U_1$ then $U_1\cup U_2=U_1$ ???

Comment: @Arthur also you just showed that $U_2\subseteq U_1\implies U_1\cup U_2$ is subspace, you didn't show the converse !!

Comment: @user211539 Yes, and I did not vote to close your question as a duplicate.  But those other questions have proofs and discussion you might find useful.

Comment: @MJD Thanks, i will search more

Comment: If $U_2\subseteq U_1$, then yes, $U_1\cup U_2=U_1$, so showing that containment implies subspace is rather simple. Showing that not-containment implies not-subspace is a bit trickier, but not much. I sketched that proof in my previous comment, starting with "Now, if neither..."

Comment: @Arthur then that means there is $v\in U_1$ such that $v\notin U_2$ and there is $x\in U_2$ such that $x\notin U_1$, but how to conclude that then $x+v\notin U_1\cup U_2$ ? (my feeling is that there's some counter example)