# $U_1 \not\subseteq U_2$, $U_2 \not\subseteq U_1$ $\implies$ $U_1 \cup U_2$ is not a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces

> Let $K$ be a field and $V$ a $K$-vector space and $U_1, U_2 \subseteq V$ subspaces of $V$ that satisfy $U_1 \not\subseteq U_2$ and $U_2 \not\subseteq U_1$. Prove that $U_1 \cup U_2$ is not a subspace of $V$.

I only found the contraposition of this argument [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1125182/prove-that-u-1-cup-u-2-is-a-subspace-of-v-iff-u-1-subseteq-u-2-or-u-2) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2182081/direct-proof-of-u-1-cup-u-2-is-subspace-of-v-implies-u-1-subset-u-2-or).

**My counterexample goes as follows:**

One obtaines $U_1 \not\subseteq U_2$ and $U_2 \not\subseteq U_1$ $\implies U_1 \cap U_2 = \emptyset$. 
For $U_1 \cup U_2$ to be a subspace of $V$ we have to prove the three subspace axioms, the first being that it's not empty.

But if we choose
$$
V := \{ p \in \mathbb{R}[t]: deg(p) < 2 \}, \quad
U_1 := \{ p \in V: p(0) = 0 \}, \text{ and }
U_2 := \{ p \in V: p(0) = 1 \}
$$
We obtain $U_1 \cap U_2 = \emptyset$.

Is my counterexample correct?

Comment: In the example, $U_2$ is not a subspace : do you think it contains zero, or is closed under addition? Two subspaces cannot have empty  intersection , since zero is in the intersection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint for the proof: Choose $u_1\in U_1\backslash U_2$ and $u_2\in U_2\backslash U_1$ prove that $u_1+u_2\not\in U_1\cup U_2$.

If by contradiction $u_1+u_2$ is an element of, say $U_1$ what can you say about $u_2$?

Answer (score 3):

> One obtains $U_1 \not\subseteq U_2$ and $U_2 \not\subseteq U_1$ $\implies U_1 \cap U_2 = \emptyset$.

No. For one thing $0\in U_1\cap U_2$ always.

> But if we choose et cetera.

$U_2$ is not a vector subspace, because $0\notin U_2$.

---

In fact your (like any other) counterexample *cannot* be correct, because the theorem is true.

Comment: I got it know, the statement is incorrect because $U_1 \not\subseteq U_2$ doesn't rule out that $U_1$ and $U_2$ share elements.