# Proof verification: $W_1\cup W_2$ is a subspace iff $W_1\subseteq W_2$ or $W_2\subseteq W_1$

Tags: linear-algebra, logic, solution-verification, vector-spaces

This is from my linear algebra textbook Sec 1.3

Question:

> Let W1 and W2 be subspaces of a vector space V. 
> Prove that W1 $\cup$ W2 is a subspace of V 
> **iff** 
> W1 $\subseteq$ W2 or W2 $\subseteq$ W1

---

Pf: 
(A) Q $\implies$ P :

$\because$ W1 $\subseteq$ W2 $\implies$ W1 $\cap$ W2 = W1 
$\because$ W2 $\subseteq$ W1 $\implies$ W1 $\cap$ W2 = W2

$\therefore$ 
 1. if W1 $\cap$ W2 = W1 $\implies$ W1 $\cup$ W2 = W2 $\subseteq$ V 
 2. if W1 $\cap$ W2 = W2 $\implies$ W1 $\cup$ W2 = W1 $\subseteq$ V

$\because$ 1 & 2 
$\therefore$ W1 $\subseteq$ W2 or W2 $\subseteq$ W1 $\implies$ $($ W1 $\cup$ W2 $)$ $\subseteq$ V 
$\therefore$ Q $\implies$ P

I am pretty confident about this part of proof. It's the other way round that I feel eerie.
Show at below

---

(B) $\sim$Q $\implies$ $\sim$P, i.e., ( W1 $\cup$ W2 ) $\nsubseteq$ V :

Assume $\sim$Q $\implies$ P, i.e., ( W1 $\cup$ W2 ) $\subseteq$ V 
then,

1. $\because$ W1, W2 $\subseteq$ V and that $\forall$ W $\subseteq$ V $\exists!$ 0 $\in$ V

    $\therefore$ W1 $\cap$ W2 $\neq$ $\varnothing$ and that 0 $\in$ W1 $\cap$ W2. 
   $\therefore$ 0 exists.
2. let 
   V = $\Bbb R^2$, W1 = { (a,b) $\in$ V : b = 0 }, W2 = { (c,d) $\in$ V : C = 0 } are subspaces of V $\implies$ W1, W2 $\subseteq$ V 
   W1 $\cap$ W2 $\neq$ W1 or W2 
   A = (1,0) $\in$ W1, B = (0,1) $\in$ W2. 
    
   A + B = (1,1) $\notin$  ( W1 $\cup$ W2 ) $\implies$ ( W1 $\cup$ W2 ) isn't closed under addition. 
   $\because$ ( W1 $\cup$ W2 ) isn't closed under addition. 
   $\therefore$ ( W1 $\cup$ W2 ) $\nsubseteq$ V $\implies$ contradicted to P.

$\because$ the contradiction in 2 
$\therefore$ $\sim$Q $\implies$ P is false 
$\therefore$ $\sim$Q $\implies$ $\sim$P is true

---

Conclusion:

$\because$ Q $\implies$ P and $\sim$Q $\implies$ $\sim$P 
$\therefore$ P $\iff$ Q

---

The two eerier parts to me are

> $\because$ the contradiction in 2 
> $\therefore$ $\sim$Q $\implies$ P is false 
> $\therefore$ $\sim$Q $\implies$ $\sim$P is true

and

> (B) $\sim$Q $\implies$ $\sim$P, i.e., ( W1 $\cup$ W2 ) $\nsubseteq$ V : 
>  
> Assume $\sim$Q $\implies$ P, i.e., ( W1 $\cup$ W2 ) $\subseteq$ V

I understand the simplest way is to proof by contradiction, but my main confuse is that can I claim:

> To prove $\sim$Q $\implies$ $\sim$P 
> Therefore assume $\sim$Q $\implies$ P 
> but $\sim$Q $\implies$ P is false 
> Thus $\sim$Q $\implies$ $\sim$P

---

Revised version

(B) $\sim$Q $\implies$ $\sim$P, i.e., ( W1 $\cup$ W2 ) $\nsubseteq$ V :

Assume $\sim$Q $\implies$ $\sim$P is **false**, meaning $\sim$Q could not imply $\sim$P 
 then,

1. $\because$ W1, W2 $\subseteq$ V and that $\forall$ W $\subseteq$ V $\exists!$ 0 $\in$ V

    $\therefore$ W1 $\cap$ W2 $\neq$ $\varnothing$ and that 0 $\in$ W1 $\cap$ W2. 
   $\therefore$ 0 exists.
2. let 
   V = $\Bbb R^2$, W1 = { (a,b) $\in$ V : b = 0 }, W2 = { (c,d) $\in$ V : C = 0 } are subspaces of V $\implies$ W1, W2 $\subseteq$ V 
   W1 $\cap$ W2 $\neq$ W1 or W2 
   A = (1,0) $\in$ W1, B = (0,1) $\in$ W2. 
    
   A + B = (1,1) $\notin$  ( W1 $\cup$ W2 ) $\implies$ ( W1 $\cup$ W2 ) isn't closed under addition. 
   $\because$ ( W1 $\cup$ W2 ) isn't closed under addition. 
   $\therefore$ ( W1 $\cup$ W2 ) $\nsubseteq$ V 
   $\therefore$ $\sim$Q $\implies$ $\sim$p is **True** 
   $\implies$ contradicted to the assumption: $\sim$Q $\implies$ $\sim$p is **False**.

$\because$ the contradiction in 2 
$\therefore$ Assumption is false $\implies$ (B) : $\sim$Q $\implies$ $\sim$P is true

Comment: No flaw in part A but a little clumsyness: better derive directly $W_1\subseteq W_2\implies W_1\cup W_2=W_2,$ and similarly with $1$ and $2$ flipped.

Comment: $W_1\cup W_2$ is always a *subset* of $V.$ The question deals with it being a *subspace*, i.e. (non-empty and) closed under the two vector space operations $+$ and $\cdot.$

Comment: There may be other flaws in B (some details are unclear, for lack of words between the formulae), but the main one is that "$(\neg Q)\implies P$ is false" does not imply "$(\neg Q)\implies\neg P$ is true".

Comment: @AnneBauval thanks for your proofreading and suggestion. Actually there is another revised version of Part B, which I finish after having an eerie feeling about the original one. However, it's over midnight, I'll provide it via editing ASAP.

Comment: New version updated!!! Thanks again. @AnneBauval

Comment: Your proof of B is wrong.You didn't prove $\neg Q\implies\neg P$ (incidentally, but not very important, you claimed to prove that implication by contradiction but you never used your hypothesis that it was false). Your point 1 (obscure, without words) is off topic. Your point 2 gives *an example* of two subspaces satisfying both $\neg Q$ and $\neg P.$ It does not prove that *every* subspaces which satisfy $\neg Q$ necessarily also satisfy $\neg P.$ (Moreover, but this is easy to fix, you wrote $W_1\cap W_2$ instead of $W_1\cup W_2$.)

Comment: I don't get it. I thought proving statement A, i.e., B->C,  is true by contradiction means: 1. Assume A is False. 2. Prove that assuming A is false will lead to contradiction, which is equivalent to  B->C is true and false at the same time. 3. Because assumption lead to contradiction, therefore, ~assumption = statement A must be correct.  (1/2)

Comment: By this understanding, I try to prove ~Q -> ~P is true by 1) assume ~Q -> ~P is false. 2) Find 1 example that satisfied ~Q imply ~P. Thus proving the assumption, ~Q imply ~ P is false, exists contradiction. 3) because the assumption will lead to contradiction, therefore ~assumption will be true.   **For step 2, I use a thm stating that m in V a vs is a subspace of V by showing 0 exists, addition closed, scalar multiplication closed. Because 0 exists, therefore I proceed to test whether addition is closed. (2/2)

Comment: If, as you seemed to intend, you proved that A is true *without using the assumption* that A is false, of course this would contradict your assumption that A is false, i.e. lead to the contradiction that A would be true and false at the same time. But such a pseudo proof by contradiction would actually be a direct proof (you began with proving that A is true), wheighed down by useless  convolutions.

Comment: The example you found satisfies ~Q and ~P.  By the only fact that it satisfies ~P, it automatically satisfies $\neg Q\implies\neg P$ (~Q is useless for that). But this *example* doesn't prove that for *every* subspaces, $\neg Q\implies\neg P$ (as commented above 51 min ago).

Comment: At the beginning of your revised version, you wrote "$\sim$P, i.e., ( W1 $\cup$ W2 \) $\nsubseteq$ V". As mentionned in my second comment yesterday, this is wrong.

Comment: There are already [many proofs of this on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=union+two+subspaces). Look for instance at [the proposed duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2897364) linked above (53 min ago), and at the 3 posts linked to it and the many posts related to it.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

First, I'd like to point out that a set being a subset of another set and a set being a subspace of another vector space are different. I think what you did in proving part (b) is to prove the contrapositive via proof by contradiction, which is a bit eerie as you said. Below is the proof that I came up with.

$P$: $W_1 \cup W_2$ is a subspace of $V$.

$\neg Q$: $W_1\not\subset W_2$ and $W_2\not\subset W_1$

Let's show that $P \land \neg Q$ leads to a contradiction, therefore $P\implies Q$.

$\neg Q$ implies $\exists w_1\in W_1$ such that $w_1\notin W_2$, and $\exists w_2\in W_2$ such that $w_2\notin W_1$.

Recall that $W_1 \cup W_2 = \{w\in V \mid w\in W_1 \text{ or } w\in W_2\}.$ Hence, $w_1\in W_1\cup W_2$ and $w_2 \in W_1\cup W_2$. Since $W_1\cup W_2$ is a subspace, it is closed under addition (+) defined on $V$. Therefore, $w_1+w_2 \in W_1\cup W_2$. This implies $w_1+w_2 \in W_1$ or $w_1+w_2 \in W_2$.

Let's show that either cases lead to a contradiction.

Suppose $w_1 + w_2 \in W_1$. Because $W_1$ is a subspace, $w_1\in W_1$ implies $-w_1\in W_1$. Therefore, $(w_1+w_2)+(-w_1) = w_2 \in W_1$. However, $\neg Q$ implies $w_2 \notin W_1$. This is a contradiction.

Similarly, suppose $w_1 + w_2 \in W_2$. Because $W_2$ is a subspace, $w_2\in W_2$ implies $-w_2\in W_2$. Therefore, $(w_1+w_2)+(-w_2) = w_1 \in W_2$. However, $\neg Q$ implies $w_1 \notin W_2$. This is a contradiction. $\blacksquare$

Comment: I am confused, isn't your claim, P⟹¬Q  leads to a contradiction, therefore P⟹Q
, equivalent to my original part (B), ~Q⟹P leads to a contradiction thus ~O⟹~P? If I get your idea correct, isn't such way of proving has been shown to exist flaws on the logic as @AnneBauvel wrote?

Comment: As far as I understand Ray's comment, I agree with it. Your proof is essentially correct but there is a big mistake in its formulation. What you proved is (happily!) *not* "that $P\implies \neg Q$ leads to a contradiction" (this would *not* prove the claim $P\implies Q$). What you proved is that $P\land\neg Q$ leads to a contradiction, i.e. you proved $\neg(P\land\neg Q),$ i.e. $(\neg P)\lor Q,$ i.e. $P\implies Q.$ Anyway, I think you'd better delete your answer, as this post is a megaduplicate, which already received many good answers.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. Just edited!